# English keyboard shortcuts & multiple input language

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, language, localization

I use the vim-like keyboard shortcuts on websites like gmail & twitter (e.g j, k, etc.).
Often I need to switch to other non-English input language to write an email and at the same time, it would be nice if I could use a *keyboard shortcuts to switch to my inbox (keys g, i).
To accomplish that, I'd need to first switch to English which makes the keyboard shortcut quite cumbersome.

Do you know of any existing solution to achieve seamless translation of non-English key strokes to English?

*any keyboard shortcut that doesn't use a modifier key. 
For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>, to bold some text would work just fine with any input language for obvious reasons (virutal key layout).

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 7, but it's not an OS issue. In fact, I don't even think it'd be considered an issue, but a feature I'd love to see.

Answer (score -1):

ALt+SHIFT should change language on the keyboard.  You will need to have more than one language set up on your keyboard.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear: my problem is the fact that I need to change the input language in order to use a certain keyboard shortcut.